# Update new table using EF Core in Web API Core 3.1 from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, webapi

I have created DbContext(Scaffold-DbContext) using EFCore in Web API Core 3.1. and after some changes and created new tables in SQL Server. I want to update new created tables in EFCore Web API Core 3.1. How can I update my all created tables?

I have tried many times as following command. but either all tables repeat or some time all tables name changes like TblUser after change (TblUsers). why?

```
caffold-DbContext "Server=vaio;Database=Company;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

i have tried
as follow

```
caffold-DbContext "Server=vaio;Database=Company;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before. So the EF is all based on code first. There no way to update you models by scaffolding.
But there is other way I'm using to solve this issue. I open second project and run scaffold command there like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "conection string here" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir "Your Dir" -Force -Tables tabeOne, tableTwo
```

In that way you get all changes you want in the new project then copy and replace all in your main project from the new one.

Comment: I have tried as above instruction but it create new DbContext only for given table and previous DbContext get deleted after run above command

Comment: That's why "open second project and run scaffold command there" ... then "copy and replace all in your main project from the new one."

Answer (score 0):

efcore is not designed for db first, reverse engineering the model from the database you cannot just run scaffold command again, you should manually update models or delete the models and rerun the scaffold,

Basically you have to add --Force flag to overwrite model with new one

from:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

> After making changes to the database, you may need to update your EF
> Core model to reflect those changes. If the database changes are
> simple, it may be easiest just to manually make the changes to your EF
> Core model. For example, renaming a table or column, removing a
> column, or updating a column's type are trivial changes to make in
> code.
>
> More significant changes, however, are not as easy to make manually.
> One common workflow is to reverse engineer the model from the database
> again using -Force (PMC) or --force (CLI) to overwrite the existing
> model with an updated one.

Answer (score -1):

finally i found a solution to update Database first DbContext that i have deleted old Model folder and then again run Scaffold-Dbcontext command. it fetched all tables from Sql server successfully.